# AWS DMS: cdc: binlog not matching between cdc and mysql rds. How to understand this

Tags: aws-dms

I am trying to do a full load + ongoing replication from RDS MYSQL to Redshift

on my RDS

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS

File                       Position Binlog_Do_DB Binlog_Ignore_DB Executed_Gtid_Set 
-------------------------- -------- ------------ ---------------- ----------------- 
mysql-bin-changelog.344451 19009
```

on my DMS i see

[image]

[image]

Why i see the binlogs are different.